# cannot do two-way cluster standarded error in python

Tags: cluster-computing, statsmodels, stat

`cluster_2ways_ols = sm.ols(formula='y ~ x', data=df).fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': np.array(df[['firmid', 'year']])}, use_t=True)`

I try to use 'groups': np.array(df[['firmid', 'year']]), the error said : Cannot change data-type for object array.

I don't know what happen. But if I only use one series such as df['year'], it works.

Comment: Convert your columns to be integer based rather than strings.  `groups` must be lists of integer IDs.

Comment: @KevinS It firmid are string and year are int. Firmid is a character string... Thus, it does not work

Comment: If you convert your string to a pandas categorical then you can get the integer values using the `codes` attribute, as in `pd.Categorical(some_str_var).codes`